# Creating a loop so this animation repeats

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop, lwjgl

I made code to draw points (to look like stars) and i made it move but how do i have this animation repeat and not just stop after a few seconds? What's the best way to do this because i don'T want to waste resources on this animation (if it does not erase the points that have lost the screen);

```
package game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;

import java.util.Random;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(Display.getDesktopDisplayMode());
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch(LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        int width = Display.getWidth();
        int height = Display.getHeight();

        System.out.println("" + width);
        System.out.println("" + height);

        gluPerspective((float) 30, 1280f / 800f, 0.001f, 100);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        Point[] points = new Point[10000];
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++) {
            points[i] = new Point((random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 100f, (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 100f, random.nextInt(200) - 200);
        }

        float speed = 0.25f;

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glTranslatef(0, 0, speed);

            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            for(Point p : points) {
                glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
            }
            glEnd();

            System.out.println("" + speed);

            Display.update();

            Display.sync(60);
        }
    }

    public static class Point {
        float x, y, z;

        public Point(float x, float y, float z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

now i have this code but the loop is very obvios, does anyone know how i can fix this?

```
package game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;

import java.util.Random;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

public class Main {

    public Main() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(Display.getDesktopDisplayMode());
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch(LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        int width = Display.getWidth();
        int height = Display.getHeight();

        System.out.println("" + width);
        System.out.println("" + height);

        gluPerspective((float) 30, 1280f / 800f, 0.001f, 100);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        Point[] points = new Point[10000];
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++) {
            points[i] = new Point((random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 100f, (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 100f, random.nextInt(200) - 200);
        }

        float speed = 0.25f;

        int count = 0;

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            count++;
            if(count < 100)
                glTranslatef(0, 0, speed);
              else
              {
                glTranslatef(0, 0, -100 * speed);
                count = 0;
              }

            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            for(Point p : points) {
                glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
            }

            glTranslatef(0, 0, width);

            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
              for(Point p : points) {
                glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
              }

            glEnd();

            Display.update();

            Display.sync(60);
        }
    }

    public static class Point {
        float x, y, z;

        public Point(float x, float y, float z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ideas? maybe i could reset it when its gone off. But i don't know how to do that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are translating the whole set of stars (the "points" array) to give the movement effect. I guess after a while, the set of stars reach to end and your screen goes blank. (all stars are out of screen) I am assuming stars are sliding horizontally and z is your horizontal direction.

The most efficient solution that comes to mind is to reset the position of the "points" to initial state when it reaches to end of screen. Make the set of stars distributed in an area that fits your screen size. And draw the stars for two times, second one is shifted for one screen width in the horizontal axis, in order to simulate continuity.

I wrote a pseudo code below; It is probably faulty but it aims to give you the idea.

```
    int count = 0;
    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      count++;
      if(count < 100)
        glTranslatef(0, 0, speed);
      else
      {
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -100*speed); // To initial position
        count = 0;
      }

      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      for(Point p : points) {
        glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
      }

      glTranslatef(0, 0, screenWidth);

      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      for(Point p : points) {
        glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
      }

      glEnd();

      System.out.println("" + speed);

      Display.update();

      Display.sync(60);
    }
```

Comment: by the way, i assumed the speed was constant, you need to change the calculation of initialPosition if it is not.

Comment: It works, but do you know how i could smooth the transition because its really obvious now? This might be because i'm using Random?

Comment: Using random is ok, but you have to get random points for Z from 0 to screenWidth. Similarly, for vertical axis; from 0 to screnHeight. Try; points[i] = new Point(random.nextInt(screenHeight+20), 0, random.nextInt(screenWidth+20)); [Assumed x is the vertical axis]

Comment: If the solution above does not solve the problem, can you be more specific about when the obviousness happens? What is the count at that moment? Is it at resetting?